# Oracle Stored Function not returning result as sql string

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I have below Oracle stored procedure which is running fine and returning result for condition `IF (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 13)`. But when i used condition `IF ((V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 12) OR (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 18))` then its not returning any result.I try to debug my code and try to run the select query where i am putting the result into variable `V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK` and returning the value and the select query is working fine. The value return in this variable will be sql string. And i am using varchar2 data type to store this sql string. So i think the data type i am using is to store sql string into variable is incorrect but not sure

```
FUNCTION BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY
(
  IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP
, IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC IN VARCHAR2
, IN_KPI_LOG_ID IN NUMBER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BODY VARCHAR2(4000) := '';    
V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK VARCHAR2(3000) := '';
V_SOAP_SERVICE_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := '';

BEGIN
Select KPI_DEF_ID INTO V_KPI_DEF_ID FROM KPI_LOGS WHERE KPI_LOG_ID = IN_KPI_LOG_ID;  

Select KT.KPI_TYPE_ID INTO V_KPI_TYPE_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_TYPE KT ON KD.KPI_TYPE = KT.KPI_TYPE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('KPI_TYPE_ID:' || V_KPI_TYPE_ID);

Select KT.CHECK_SQL INTO V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK KT ON KD.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK_ID = KT.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK' || V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK);

Select SP.SOAP_SERVICE_NAME INTO V_SOAP_SERVICE_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION KD JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE SP ON KD.SOAP_SERVICE_ID = SP.SOAP_SERVICE_ID WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = V_KPI_DEF_ID;

    BODY := to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13) || Chr(10);       

IF ((V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 12) OR (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 18)) THEN
    BODY := BODY || 'SQL USED:' || V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK || Chr(13) || Chr(10);
  ELSE IF (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 13) THEN 
    BODY := BODY || 'SOAP_SERVICE:' || Chr(13) || Chr(10);
    BODY := BODY || V_SOAP_SERVICE_NAME || Chr(13) || Chr(10);        
  END IF;
END IF;

BODY := BODY || 'ALERT_DESCRIPTION:' || to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_LOG_DESC);

    RETURN BODY;
END BUILD_ALERT_EMAIL_BODY;
```

When i debug my code then its returning the result as below which is correct :

```
KPI_TYPE_ID:18
SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK:select CASE WHEN (o.cnt = 0) THEN 0 ELSE round((r.cnt / o.cnt)*100,3) END from (select count(*) as cnt from rate_errors where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ||'0000' ) r cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from SDR_O2
      where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000'
    ) o
```

Comment: Please provide the data, i.e. create and insert statements. You can post SQL Fiddle test case.

Comment: Hi Lalit why do you need create and insert statement ? Should i provide you an example of Select query result where i am storing the result into varialbe V_SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK ?

Comment: Well, it seems, the V_KPI_TYPE_ID you are getting with the query simply doesn't match 12 or 18.

Comment: Hi Thorsten when i debug my code in sql developer and while debugging  when i provide parameter in BUILT_EMAIL_ALERT_BODY with IN_KPI_LOG_ID then its returing the value as KPI_TYPE_ID:18
SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK:select CASE WHEN (o.cnt = 0) THEN 0 ELSE round((r.cnt / o.cnt)*100,3) END from (select count(*) as cnt from rate_errors where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ||'0000' ) r cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from SDR_O2
      where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000'
    ) o

Comment: Add DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('KPI_TYPE_ID in first if ' || V_KPI_TYPE_ID); after the first IF condition. Remove SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK output. Not needed

Comment: when i try to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('KPI_TYPE_ID:' || V_KPI_TYPE_ID) inside if then its not returning any result

Comment: yes. so somehow it is not going in the if condition. Are you sure that KT.KPI_TYPE_ID is number not varchar?

Comment: yes Utsav KPI_TYPE_ID is Number and its always returning number value.

Comment: As i said its returning the result for V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 13.

Comment: hi utsav i understood the error now...when i comment the sql for soap_service then it works for system_sql_check. When i comment the code for system_sql_check then it works for soap_service and returns the result. But dont know how to correct it.

Comment: I can try recreate your code later after office hours. Lets see if someone finds a way to correct till then. Please update if you come any closer

Comment: Yes Utsav thank you. I understood now the problem is becuase of if else condition for sure.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
  IF (V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 12 OR V_KPI_TYPE_ID = 18) THEN
```

Let me know if it still doesn't return result

Comment: add dbms_output.put_line inside both if and else parts, and print the values of V_KPI_TYPE_ID to see what it returns.

Comment: Also how are you inputting value of V_KPI_TYPE_ID? I dont see it coming as input or getting set anywhere in the code.

Comment: I am sorry while editing my code i forgot to put in the question. Please check my edited question. I try to debug my code and V_KPI_TYPE_ID is returning correctly as 18

Comment: But is it coming in the first IF block or else block. Try dbms_output.put_line and check please.

Comment: i have edited my code and use dbms_output.put_line and its returning the result as : KPI_TYPE_ID:18
SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK:select CASE WHEN (o.cnt = 0) THEN 0 ELSE round((r.cnt / o.cnt)*100,3) END from (select count(*) as cnt from rate_errors where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ||'0000' ) r cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from SDR_O2
      where id > to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000'
    ) o

Comment: when i try to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('KPI_TYPE_ID:' || V_KPI_TYPE_ID) inside if then its not returning any result

Answer (score -1):

Modify the below line in your code

```
BODY := to_char(IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') || Chr(13) || Chr(10);
```

like this and try-

```
BODY := 'to_char(' || IN_ALERT_LOGS_TIMESTAMP || ',''DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'')' || Chr(13) || Chr(10);
```

Also modify wherever BODY is assigned with to_char function which is sql.